# Unity - Make only -1 and 1 be variable options to be placed in the Inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was having an issue with one of my variables in which I only want it to be -1 or 1.  I know I can use an IF statement to take care of that in OnValidate() to see if it is either 1 or -1 but I was just curious if there was something already built in to handle these situations, for example like [Range(0,999)].  Is there something built in that can limit the variables of my choice or is having IF statement checks in my OnValidate() the way to go?

Comment: If it is only 2 values why not make it a bool ?

Comment: @deathismyfriend I use the -1 and 1 for inverted variables for my character movement.

Comment: @deathismyfriend Also this is going to be something on the Unity asset store so my goal is to only have variables be set with what they are intended for and not allow them to put in numbers that can make, for example, the character movement more confusing or harder to understand.

Comment: @deathismyfriend Actually I do see where you are coming from and I think I can change the code to make this work as a bool for the inspector would be more appealing to users and easier to understand.  But let me change this from 2 to maybe 3+ variables.  How would this still apply as in the original question?  Thank you for that input though as I have no idea why I could not see that before.

Comment: If It is 3+ it can't be a bool and i would then use the range attribute as it keeps you from doing if else statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For -1 or 1, maybe you want an `enum` field? Unity will provide a dropdown of possible values for you to pick from. A bool also works for just two cases, but if -1 and 1 have some meaning outside of what they are as numbers, maybe an `enum` of named possibilities will be good.

Also check out [`EditorGUI.IntSlider`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.IntSlider.html) for an integer range slider, and [`EditorGUI.Slider`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.Slider.html) for real numbers. It's a bit more complicated than the attributes or plain old fields, but maybe it'll work for you.

EDIT: Another thing to check out is [`OnValidate`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html). This might be the simplest way: this event is called when a field changes, and you can force the field to whatever value you want. For example, you could check the field and set it to 1 if the input value is `>= 0` and -1 if `< 0`.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  Not familiar with these so I need to read up on them a bit.

Comment: Sure thing. Added another option that is even simpler and accomplishes what you ask for, but maybe not what you really want.

Comment: Yup OnValidate is currently what I am using.  I was just hoping there was something built in like [Range(x,y)] but it looks like there isn't anything like that.

Comment: Whoops, I totally missed that part of your question.